# web api odata service - return complex type

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i want to create web api odata service that return reault type which consist of collection data member and additional members like this service return:

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$filter=Address/City eq 'Redmond'

as you can see the result type is consist of collection data member and additional members

can anyone send me a sample how to do it?

i can't succeed to create this kind of complex type and to be able filter the collection items by there values

as yuo can see in this query it return all the result without filter the items

services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers

i want to be able filter this type like this:

services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$filter=Address/City eq 'Redmond'

in this query i managed to filter the collection member items and still returning the other data members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to implement filters like: services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$filter=Address/City eq 'Redmond'

Please check the sample at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/903afc4e11df#Samples%2fNet4%2fCS%2fWebApi%2fODataServiceSample%2fReadMe.txt

It has a supplier and address model with queryable attribute. It should work with the same $filter query.

Answer (score 0):

Odata support was implicit in asp.net webapi RC. 
You just had to return a IQueryable from you Actions and mark it with [QueryableAttribute].
Only this much supported querystring based data filtering.

I was a bit disappointed when I saw the [QueryableAttribute] doesnt build in RTM.

In RTM it’s available as a separate package, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData on Nuget in a preview/alpha form. Full release is coming later this fall. You can grab it from here(http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData). There is a nice overview post available (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx)

Comment: i know how to filter querable data .
my problem that the object i want to filter consist of collection and some other data members not collection type.
so i dont know how to implemet iqueriable
can you give me example how to convert tyoe to iqueriable without using a collection or implemet ienumerable
because than the fillter won't work on the sub type